# Spatial join in GEE, so that points lying within a polygon get properties from the polygon

Tags: google-earth-engine, intersection, spatial-join, feature-collection

I have some ROI polygons with a unique property 'label', and I have sample points lying within the different polygons. I want to add the label property from the polygons to the points. I manage to separate the points according to which polygon they are in, but the property 'label' is missing.

```
var ROI_1 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-117.3226, 41.1803],[-117.3226, 38.99536], [-113.807065, 38.9955], [-113.8070, 41.18032]]], null, false),
        { "label": "red", "system:index": "0"})
var ROI_2 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-109.7201, 40.44864], [-109.7201, 38.42952],[-106.512135, 38.42951], [-106.5121, 40.44896]]], null, false),
        { "label": "green", "system:index": "0" })
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection(
        [(ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-116.114189, 40.7822]), {"system:index": "0"})),
         (ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-107.874443, 40.01249]),{"system:index": "1"})),
         (ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-114.3124, 39.4545724]),{"system:index": "2"})),
         (ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-116.1361, 39.2510006]),{"system:index": "3"})),
         (ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-115.60881, 40.310154]),{"system:index": "4"})),
         (ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-114.9935, 40.6323241]),{"system:index": "5"})),
         (ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-107.59389, 39.108544]),{"system:index": "6"})
          )]);

Map.addLayer(f1, {color: 'red'}, 'red')
Map.addLayer(f2, {color: 'green'}, 'green')
Map.addLayer(pts)

// Load the primary collection: ROIs
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([ROI_1, ROI_2]); //polygons with unique property: 'label'

// Load the secondary collection: sample points
var points = pts; 

print(polygons, 'ROIs')

// Define a spatial filter as geometries that intersect.
var spatialFilter = ee.Filter.intersects({
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 10
});

// Define a save all join.
var saveAllJoin = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'label',
});

// Apply the join.
var intersectJoined = saveAllJoin.apply(polygons, points, spatialFilter);

// Add label as a property.
intersectJoined = intersectJoined.map(function(polygons) {
  var keepProperty = polygons.get('label');
  // Return the point features with a new property: 'label'.
  return pts.set('label', polygons.get('label'))
  
});
  
print(intersectJoined, 'intersectJoined')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably misunderstood how the `saveAll()` join works.

Your script add a property to each polygon containing the matching points. You control the name of that property with `matchesKey` on the `saveAll()` join. You set that key to `label`, overwriting the label you're actually interested in.

So for starters, you want to use a different `matchesKey`. Then you want to extract the the matching points from each polygon and assign the label to each individual point. Finally, assuming you want to have a collection of points, you have to `flatten()` the results, as it is a collection with collections.

```
var saveAllJoin = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'points'
})

var intersectJoined = saveAllJoin
  .apply({
    primary: polygons, 
    secondary: points, 
    condition: spatialFilter
  })
  .map(function(polygon) {
    var label = polygon.get('label')
    var points = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(polygon.get('points')))
      .map(function (point) {
        return point.set('label', label)
      })
    return points
  }).flatten()
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/60731336a8e0538dc125e125c6e56884